# Внешние зависимости Nuxt

Tags: vue.js

Начал разбираться с vue.js и для того чтобы сделать SSR в документации рекомендуется использовать nuxt. 
Для моей задачи требуется подгрузить OpenLayers библиотеку, чтобы отображать метки на карте.

```
export default {
  head: {
    link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/css/ol.css"' }
    ],
    scripts: [
      { src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/build/ol.js', type: 'text/javascript' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getMap: function () {

    }
  }
}
```

Так погружаются внешние зависимости в nuxt. 
Проблема в том что css подгрузился, а вот js script нет.
Что сделано не правильно?

Comment: Можно ссылку где сказано что так можно подключить и js?

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/faq/)

Comment: @Vyacheslav, по твоей ссылке свойство называется `script`: `head: {
    script: [` а у тебя `scripts`

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам поможет [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)
Вот пример, как я использую во Vue.js yandex maps, быть может он вам чем-то поможет:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
        <h1>Карта</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                map: {}
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            $.getScript('//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU').then(() => {
                const ymaps = global.ymaps;
                ymaps.ready(() => {
                    new ymaps.Map("map", {
                        center: [55.76, 37.64],
                        zoom: 12
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

P.S. нет возможности попробовать, но тут нет нникаких `type: 'text/javascript'`, может в этом ошибка? Пример подключения из [доков](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/faq/)

```
script: [
  { src:'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' }
],
```

Comment: Сегодня посмотрю

Comment: Ваш вариант попробовать не удалось, так как не понял как подключить jQuery(всё та же ошибка что и прежде). Но обнаружил интересное: если попробовать повставлять библиотеки в режиме реального времени(при запущенном dev), то библиотеки таки подключаются. Только все равно не работают должным образом. И после перезагрузки страницы они снова исчезают.

Comment: `npm install jquery --save`

Код вставки в app.js (корневой файл для компиляции webpack-ом у меня) `window.$ = require('jquery');`

Comment: https://github.com/Shleif91/vuex-example репозиторий без nuxt, но можно посмотреть как подключал в `js/app.js`